# How to connect drawer to animated icon button in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-animation, drawer

I want to have Animated button icon on `AppBar` (thats always visible), to call a Drawer in my app. To have AppBar always visible even while Drawer is opened, i used this method: I had to put AppBar to main Scaffold, then passed a child: Scaffold and put Drawer inside.

I managed to get button working through IF statement and `_scaffoldKey.currentState` . So button works and animates from hamburger to arrow while opening and closing Drawer, but I also want to implement animating the button while opening/closing drawer with swiping, or while drawer is opened, by tapping outside drawer. Is there any way to do it ?

I'm kind of beginner in Flutter here is part of my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool _isDrawerOpen = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  }



  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }

  void _handleOnPressed() {
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = !isPlaying;
      isPlaying
          ? _animationController.forward()
          : _animationController.reverse();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      primary: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          "Drawer animation",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.black45),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: AnimatedIcon(
              icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow, progress: _animationController),
          onPressed: () {
            if (!_isDrawerOpen) {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
            } else {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
            setState(() {
              _isDrawerOpen = !_isDrawerOpen;
            });
            _handleOnPressed();
          },
        ),
      ),

      body: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        drawer: Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("prve"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),


        body: Container(
          child: CustomButton(),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're mixing the terms trying to achieve all kinds of component behaviours at once. I would suggest looking into the material specs for a better understanding of how it's supposed to work: https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer. For example, only a modal drawer should be dismissed by tapping the scrim (outside of the drawer) or swiping - while what you're making doesn't have a scrim (AppBar always visible).

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, it seems that you'd like to animate the button when swiping the Drawer. What you can do here is add `onDrawerChanged` on the `Scaffold` containing the `Drawer`. This should detect the gesture if the Drawer is being opened or closed.

```dart
Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  onDrawerChanged: (onDrawerChanged){
    debugPrint('onDrawerChanged? $onDrawerChanged');
    // onDrawerChanged is called on changes in drawer direction
    // true - gesture that the Drawer is being opened
    // false - gesture that the Drawer is being closed
    onDrawerChanged
        ? _animationController.forward()
        : _animationController.reverse();
  },
  ...
)
```

With this setup, `_handleOnPressed()` can be removed from being called inside `IconButton(onPressed: (){});`

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

you can just do like this for drawer Open and then closed

```
onDrawerChanged: (change) {
    setState(() {
      isplaying = !isplaying;
      isplaying
          ? animationController.forward()
          : animationController.reverse();
    });
  }
```

then add this to **IconButton onPressed** method

```
onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
        }
```